# WireGuard does not work on multiple clients at once?

Tags: wireguard

So I have an Ubuntu Server which is used as the VPN server and 2 clients.

For some reason, the second one can't connect to the internet (it can't be pinged and it can ping to the others).

Here are my configs:

Server

```
[Interface]

Address = 10.0.0.1/24

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

ListenPort = 51820

PrivateKey = server private key


[Peer]

PublicKey = client1 public

AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32


[Peer]

PublicKey = client2 public

AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32
```

Client side (10.0.0.2 is peer1 from the server, 10.0.0.3 is peer2)

```
[Interface]

PrivateKey = client private key

Address = 10.0.0.3/24

MTU = 1420

PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu

PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -D FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu

DNS = 10.0.0.3

ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]

PublicKey = server public key

Endpoint = server ip:51820

AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

The problem is with peer2. It has no internet access.

As I understood by searching online is that I can't have two clients with AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 . I'm using it because I want to route all the traffic through the VPN. So if I can't have it on 2 clients, how can I route the traffic through the VPN on both?

Comment: `I can't have two clients with AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` false

Comment: Do the clients have different private keys? Do both clients successfully perform a wireguard handshake? Are packets from client2 received on the server?